# Control in Row with MinimumSize laying over the lower Row

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a design like this:

[image: Winforms Design]
And now my problem is that when the Form Window is big enough that the Panel 1 has more space than its `MinimumSize` it looks good, but when there is not enough space it is laying over the second row.

That looks like:

**Enough space:**
[image: Row Normal]
**Not enough space:**
[image: Row painted Over]

How can i fix it that when my Panel exceeds the row height that a scroll bar is shown and it is not laying over the lower rows?

Comment: Do you want to make the Panel1 lie under the row 2??? You just have to right click the Panel2 (at design time) and select 'Bring to Front'. Then your Panel1 is always under the Panel2 (row2). This can also be done using code with 2 methods BringToFont() and SendToBack(). I think that's exactly what you want. :)

Comment: that works for the visual view of that, but than my Panel 1 don't enables scrolling when it is the underneath. I think i have to add another panel that scrolling will be enabled if Panel 1 exceeds the row ?

Comment: if you want to support auto scroll for your Panel1. You can add a Label (with Text = "" and BackColor=Transparent) to your Panel1 at the fixed point: `Label label1 = new Label(){Left = 0, Top = 840, Height = 2}; panel1.Controls.Add(label1);`. And set the `AutoScroll` of Panel1 to true. That should work!